# I want to add prouct id,order_id to items tables when customer click confirm

Tags: laravel

I want to add `product_id`, `order_id`, `Price`, `Quantity` to **Order_items tables** when customer click confirm. (I used Session for Cart)

I tried this code

```
In controller
        $cartItems = session()->get('cart');

        foreach($cartItems as $item) {
            $order->items()->attach($item->id, ['price'=> $item->price, 'quantity'=> $item->quantity]);
        }
```

in Order Model,

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_items', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price');
}
```

Tell me a solution for me or if you know any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

your code make a journey to DB for every item in $cartItems ...

you can make a bulk insert using [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery)()

witch Create a new query builder for the pivot table.

```
 $cartItems = session()->get('cart');
 $arrayToAdd=[];
  foreach($cartItems as $item) {
        $arrayToAdd[]=['product_id'=>$item->id,'price'=> $item->price, 'quantity'=> $item->quantity,'order_id'=>$order->id]);
        } 

 $order->items()->newPivotQuery()->insert($arrayToAdd);
```